# Running a second instance of TestNG programmatically and appending test results

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, testng

I have a situation where I'm trying to re-use integration tests from one project to additionally hit a near-identical, essentially pass-through REST service (the endpoints are the same except for the headers).  The secondary pass-through service is a common endpoint for all public interactions.  To make it simpler, I'll call that `public-api` and the original service where the tests live `private-api`

We're using a retrofit api to actually make the rest calls in combination with a couple hacks to make the headers more configurable.

The tests run fine when running as integration tests via failsafe in the `private-api`, but in the `public-api` we have a little more configuration that needs to happen programmatically before launching the tests.  To that end I've written a test method:

```
@Test(groups = {"test"})
@Parameters({"xmlTestConfigFilePath"})
public void runCommonTests(String xmlTestConfigFilePath)
{
    log.info("Launching common test library");

    try
    {
        System.setProperty("it.localServiceBaseUrl", "localhost:8080/public-endpoint");

        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        testNG.addListener(tla);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(new LinkedList<>(new Parser(xmlTestConfigFilePath).parse()));
        testNG.run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Exception thrown while executing common tests", e);
        assertTrue(false);
    }
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

**Note:** xmlTestConfigFilePath is intentionally different from -DsuiteXmlFile to allow a secondary xml configuration for the common tests

The problem is, I'm not getting any useful output from the common tests when running this way.  Running `mvn clean test` results in the following output:

```
===============================================
wfm_public_api_suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 6
===============================================
```

No stack traces, nothing useful.  Is there a way to append the results of the common test run to the "driver" test run? add it to the session somehow?

Comment: If you are putting your Testng.run command in an "@Test", you are essentially invoking TestNG twice.  How are you invoking your tests?  From eclipse?  A configuration failure would indicate some setup steps, do you have a "@BeforeXXX" defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes, we're invoking TestNG twice, that's what I was describing.  I'm wanting to know if I can access the existing testNG session's result listeners somehow so I can call `testNG.addListener(...)` or something similar and have it all get combined